# Freeware tool to change playback speed of avi file

Tags: video, speed, avi, framerate

I am looking for a Windows tool that can convert the framerate of an avi video file. Basically I want it to play at 4 times the speed.

The video itself should technically not really be 120fps but still 30fps. It should just resample the source video so that it seems to be playing at a speed which is 4 times as fast, which should result in the same effect as playing the original in 120fps.

I tried using VirtualDub, but it results in frozen frames every 5 seconds for about 1 second.

Comment: Interesting, would you mind sharing what kind of videos your thinking off? Length, resolution and frequency?

Comment: the source avi is 5mins, 320x240, 30fps.

Comment: on what     OS?

Comment: on windows vista

Comment: Just curious but why do you have to change it? What do you need the video for?

Comment: What kind of hardware are you using? Since it might be that your GPU can't handle the video conversion too well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out what i did wrong in virtualdub. basically i have to use both options one to make the video faster and one to sample it down again.

Answer (score 3):

This might help you - [AVI Frame Rate Changer 1.10](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/AVI_Frame_Rate_Changer.htm).

> AVI Frame Rate Changer allows you to
>   modify the frame rate of a
>   pre-rendered AVI File without
>   re-rendering the AVI data. Full Delphi
>   source code is included. Please note
>   that it may not work well with certain
>   AVI files and you may want to keep a
>   backup copy of the modified AVI file
>   (just in case).
>
> The most important thing what AVI Fram
>   Rate changer does is... change the
>   frame rate of AVI movies(big surprise,
>   right?). This is all what AVI Frame
>   Rate changer does, it has no other
>   features. You can change the rate from
>   1.000 to 60.000. The Avi Frame Rate changer zip-file provided by AM
>   Software provides the source code from
>   this tool too, so you can understand
>   how they made the tool.

[image]

Comment: +1 This program seems to be what you're looking for. I wanted to see if I could find more info on it and stumbled on an alternative, so I added it below.

Comment: thank you! i gave it a try, but it results in the same freezing frames every 5 seconds for 1 second. so maybe there is a problem with my source file.

Comment: @Ivo they are both the same software, on the other site it mentions AM Software as the company as well :P

Comment: Lol I was unsure, since the names didn't really match, but now I look at the screenshot they do!

Comment: Fixed that problem :P

Answer (score 2):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and [MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) (MPlayer’s Movie Encoder) are IMO the best video manipulation programs around there. Here, you'll need Mencoder.

[MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/mencoder.html) has a "-speed" option that you may want to play with. "-speed 1" is realtime. Try 0.5 and 2 for testing. Not in the GUI, so you'll have to go command line.

Comment: thank you! i finally got it running. but even here i have the problem that every 5 seconds it jumps ahead a few frames and then shows a frozen frame for about 1 second.

Comment: Weird, it should just create a perfectly playable 2mn30 avi at 60 FPS. Do you have enough hardware power?

Comment: yep, my hardware should be more than sufficient. i think the problem is more with the source avi, since this problem doesnt seem to be related to the tool i use.

Answer (score 0):

[VLC](http://videolan.org) can slow it down, it does it by playing it back at half speed, or quarter or whatever you make it. Not sure about converting and saving it that way, but for just playback it works.

Comment: thanks. yes i am looking for converting and saving